# Can't get headset and headset mic to work simultaneously

Tags: usb, sound, microphone, headset

I've been trying to get my headset mic to work (mainly for use on discord) for a week, and no matter which way I try I run into one of the following issues: Only the mic works, Only the audio works, or both work but my system audio plays through the input.

Today i went and bought a 3.5mm splitter in hopes of an easy fix, and at that point the system audio always played through the input. I found a 3.5mm to USB splitter/controller of sorts that came with my headset and thought that was my solution, but still running into the same issues. Although with the USB-c both mic and headset work in the same port, but not at the same time.

Hardware: https://www.nzxt.com/products/h500-matte-white

https://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/headsets/cloud-gaming-headset?partnum=HX-HSCL-SR/NA&ktc_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=Cj0KCQjww_f2BRC-ARIsAP3zarEWA9i1ljVpnRSkxTOT70yA74vq5FuAzoSoMXhLpV-pddml7ezx9psaAu7jEALw_wcB

I'm very new to both PC building and Ubuntu so I apologize if it's an obvious fix. Thanks!

Comment: The device may need software if you are connecting via USB.  Otherwise, it should have two 3.5mm plugs, one for the headset and the other for the mic.

Comment: @nmath i'm fine with using 3.5mm plugs, but as i said i'm still running into issues when going that route.

Comment: did you try pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control )  or  alsamixer  to set input/output ?

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue using

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo dpkg -P force all pulseaudio
sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse

then

sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio

but I have to do it again after every reboot

Comment: Sorry for the formatting in my previous comment, i'm not sure how to do it correctly.